# Why isn't the debugger gede --args show an error with vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging

Trying to debug my code with a debugger that has a GUI like gede --args. but when I run the command it says "gede: command not found". Anyone know why it says this? I used the debugger a couple weeks ago and it worked fine now it doesnt exsist?

tried to see if I wrote it wrong but nothing

Comment: It means the program `gede` is not the search path as used by your debugger.  If you can revise the title for clarity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code doesn't matter. I am just trying to run the debugger gede --args but it says the error I posted. I am not sure why since ive used it before and it works fine